# If I claim a monster token from the cup, do I pick at random?

Tags: arkham-horror

One of the Other World encounters says

> Pass a **Luck (-1) check** to claim a monster trophy from the cup (even if it is **Endless**)....

Does this mean I pick randomly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe so. I don't think there are specific rules, but:

- Every other interaction with the cup is drawing randomly.
- Other encounters with rewards like this instead say "Draw a monster from the cup and take it as a monster trophy, even if it has the Endless ability." or even "Draw one monster trophy at random from the cup."

If this were meant to be different and let you hunt through for what you want, I assume it'd explicitly say so.